# how do i use Pyautogui locate on screen function within only one application window instead of the whole screen

Tags: python, image-recognition, pyautogui

I'm trying to find a way to make my automation bot faster I realized that by searching only within the application window instead of the whole screen would give it a speed post how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us some code or what you already tried.

But you could use `pywinauto` package to use the application you want. For more details please check the [How does it work](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-does-it-work).

You can get all applications open from `Desktop` function as:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
window = [w.window_text() for w in windows]
```

So if you `print(window)` you will have for example:

```
['Zoom', 'python - how do i use Pyautogui locate on screen function within only one application window instead of the whole screen - Stack Overflow', 'Dictations - OneNote']
```